# Двоичный циклический сдвиг

Tags: алгоритм, мк-61

Здравствуйте, друзья. Подскажите, пожалуйста, оптимальный способ реализации двоичного циклического сдвига (вращения) 32-разрядного значения влево на 11 разрядов на языке МК-61.

Comment: Не, извините, я только на БЭСМ могу.

Comment: Да, остаётся надеяться, что ещё не все позабыли те славные времена.

Значение предполагаю разместить в двух регистрах по 16 битов в каждом. Побитовые операции имеются и на аппаратном уровне, а вот сдвигов и т. п. нету: предполагалось, что человек сам сделает, если надо будет. Только как?

Comment: БЭСМ -- это что? Они разные были.

Comment: @Котик, а куда делся комментарий про БЭСМ-2? Не желаете выдавать её местонахождение?

Comment: БЭСМ (точнее, БЭСМ-6 и всё с ними связанное) умерли вместе с нашими ПМК. А вместе с ними и всё наше компьютеростроение как часть высокотехнологичной промышленности, которую уничтожили на взлёте.

Comment: @alexlz Я подумал, что шутка не очень и стер его :)

Comment: @Русский, какие трагические слова о взлете отечественного компьютеростроения. 

А Вы знаете *на сколько* БЭСМ-6 был **именно наш** ? 

Если интересно - поинтересуйтесь ТЗ на эту разработку (систему команд).

Comment: Да уж поболее наш, чем, например, современные "разработки" РФ. В области ПМК к ним можно причислить печально известные МК-152 и МК-161 на китайских микросхемах.

Comment: @Русский да уж. В БЭСМ-6 китайских транзисторов не было... А "на взлёте" -- это когда ешё шасси не убрано?

Comment: Нет, "на взлёте" - это когда мы могли себе позволить создавать такие шедевры технического прогресса, как, например ОК "Буран" или же ракетные системы С-300, Тунгуска (да и вообще вся наша космическая и военная сфера в вопросах использования ЭВМ тут пример). А чего только разрабатывавшийся потомок БЭСМ-6 "Эльбрус" стоил... Если бы не два фактора, первый из которых - уничтожение нашего государства, а второй - преступная политика руководства по отношению к новым разработкам, то мы бы сейчас достигли больших высот в компьютеростроении.

Comment: Кстати, я так и не нашёл подробных сведений о ТЗ на разработку системы команд БЭСМ-6. Что в нём интересного содержалось? Не уж-то позаимствовали где? Никогда не слыхал.

Comment: В ТЗ было требование об исполнимости кода Fortran программ (компилятор не помню) для CDC 6600.

Т.о. архитектура БЭСМ-6 была некоторым образом предопределена. В основном же это, конечно, наша (и очень удачная) разработка. Но не последняя (из не цельнодраных и концептуальнодраных). Поинтересуйтесь М-10

Comment: @Русский 

    преступная политика руководства по отношению к новым разработкам, то мы бы сейчас достигли больших высот в компьютеростроении.

Как было написано в журнале "Крокодил": "А вот на Западе так не умеют, чтобы компьютер -- и без единого гвоздя"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Встроенные битовые операции тут не помогут, т.к. нет даже нециклического сдвига.

Поэтому делаем в десятичной системе: в одном из регистров старшие 16 бит, в другом - младшие.

Из старших 16 бит отделяем левые 11 бит (делением нацело на 2 в 5 степени), запоминаем. Остальные 5 бит тоже отделяем (для этого надо как-то остаток от прошлого деления получить), умножаем на 2 в 11 степени. Из младших 16 бит точно так же выделяем старшие 11 бит, прибавляем их к старшему байту. Остаток опять же умножаем на 2 в 11 степени, прибавляем те 11 бит, которые сохранили в самом начале.

Comment: Спасибо. Надо теперь перевести этот алгоритм в код, хотя это уже не сложно. Тот же остаток, к примеру, в 5 команд вычисляется:
ПN   /   {x}   ИПN   *

Comment: @Русский, остаток точнее будет, если целое частное умножить на делитель и вычесть из делимого.

Comment: О, согласен, большое спасибо. А то действительно, в моём варианте иногда приходилось округлять до целого.

Comment: Вобщем, получился такой код (немного неоптимальный, но работает):
ИП0 3 2 / [x] П2 3 2 * ИП0
- /-/ 2 0 4 8 * П3 ИП1 3
2 / [x] П4 3 2 * ИП1 - /-/
2 0 4 8 * ИП2 + П1 ИП3 ИП4
+ П0 С/П

Comment: Не удержался, достал девайс из стола :) Да, все верно. Оптимизировать вроде особо нечего, разве что 32 и 2048 заранее в регистры занести и при необходимости доставать, получится на 8 байт короче.

Comment: Радует, что они ещё в ходу.

Немного оптимизировать можно, например, так:

    2 П5 0 П6 ИП1 ПП19 П7 ИП2 ПП
    19 ИП3 + П2 ИП7 ИП4 + П1 С/П 3
    2 / [x] КП5 3 2 * КИП6 - /-/
    2 0 4 8 * В/О

Здесь, правда, используются не Р0 и Р1, а Р1 и Р2 для хранения значения. Занеся заранее в регистры 32 и 2048, удастся освободить ещё 5 ячеек.